# How to get data type of variables of a class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have class like

```
 export class Model {
   name: string;
   size: number;
}
```

if I try to get typeof these variables like below, it returns undefined.

```
model: Model;
 .
 .
 .
this.model = new Model();
console.log(typeof (this.model.size));
```

I tried to make class with constructor.

```
export class Model{        
        constructor(public q: string, public size?: number) {}
}
```

And I tried to get type of variables.

```
 this.model = new Model('', null);
 console.log(this.model.size)
```

It returns object. I tried toType method

```
toType = function(obj) {
    return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase()
  }
```

And

```
console.log( this.toType (this.model.size));
```

It returns null.

How can I get variable type correctly without assigning values?

Comment: Is this in typescript? Because there's a lot of things in your question that aren't valid JS

Comment: Yes. typescript

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `emitDecoratorMetadata` and `experimentalDecorators` option in conjunction with the `reflect-metadata`  package

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
// Decorator does nothing but metadata is emitted only for decorated symbols by the compiler so we need an empty decorator
function EmitType(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol){

}

export class Model {
    @EmitType name: string;
    @EmitType size: number;
    @EmitType child: Model;
    @EmitType data :  { test: string };
}

// Will output function String() { … }
console.log(Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", Model.prototype, "name"));

// Will output function Number() { … }
console.log(Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", Model.prototype, "size"));

// Will output function Model() { … }
console.log(Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", Model.prototype, "child"));

// Will output function Object() { … }
console.log(Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", Model.prototype, "data"));
```

The value stored as metadata is the type constructor, so for custom classes it will be the constructor for the class. For interfaces and other types that do not have constructors, the type will always be `Object`

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the code you have shared does not appear to be valid JS. Another pattern I noticed was that you were never actually assigning the values to instance properties in your classes.

Here is a simple example. Hope it helps.

```js
class Test { 
  constructor(a,b){
    // Make sure you assign the values to instance properties
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
} 

// Create a new instance passing different typed arguments
var t = new Test('one',1);

// Test the types
console.log(typeof t.a); //string
console.log(typeof t.b); //number
```

Comment: Yes I know. I want to get type of variables dynamically without assigning values.